# How to insert HTML fragment to HTML template using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have an HTML template and a div created programmatically in Ruby:

```
<div id="child_div">
 ....
</div>
```

How can I insert this div to the template:

```
<html>
  <body>
  <div id="div1">
  ...

  <div id = "div2">
  //need to insert the child div here 
   </body>
   </html>
```

after parsing the template using Nokogiri?

Answer (score 0):

You can save your Nokogiri HTML-Fragment into a controller instance variable like

```
@xml_fragment = Model.build_custom_xml
```

And in your view:

```
    <html>
      <body>
      <div id="div1">
      ...
      <div id = "div2">
         <%= raw xml_fragment.to_xml %>
      </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using nokogiri I would do:

```
html =  Nokogiri::HTML("<html> <body><div id='div1'></div><div id='div2'></div></body></html>")
```

Create the `child_div`:

```
child_div =  Nokogiri::XML::Node.new("div", html)
```

Assign `id`

```
child_div.set_attribute('id','child_div')
```

And fill with content:

```
child_div.content = "My Content"
```

And assign `child_div` to a parent:

```
child_div.parent = html.at_css "div#div2"
```

Perhaps not the most DRY solution but it gives you:

```
    html.to_html
 => "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html> <body>\n<div id=\"div1\"></div>\n<div id=\"div2\"><div id=\"child_div\">My Content</div></div>\n</body>\n</html>\n"
```